# jquery fade toggle fails in bootstrap site

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and jQuery on my website. The problem is that when I use `fadeToggle()` on a `div`, it's not showing, it is hidden all the time. Can anyone suggest what the problem is or an alternative way to solve it?

Comment: Unless you post some code to show what are you trying to achieve no one is going to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap "hide" class, it will not fadeIn.So if you want to do fadeToggle effect, then remove the hide class from the div and make style="display:none". Or use toggleClass('hide'). Thinks it will solve your problem .